# Using $addFields to Add Sub Property to Root of Mongo Document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am creating a Mongo view n order to hand the front-end client the data shapes as necessary. Originally I have a document that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : <value>, 
    "region" : "Midwest", 
    "dob" : ISODate("1989-07-21T05:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "paymentOption" : {
        "_id" : <value>, 
        "anotherProp" : <value>
        "coverage" : {
                "status" : "active", 
                "coverageEnd" : ISODate("2020-07-31T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                "coverageStart" : ISODate("2018-08-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        },
    }
}
```

... and what I want to do is take "coverage" from within "paymentOption" and put this on the root of the document with a property titled "coverage", and then afterwards, remove "paymentOption".

To do that I tried this:

```
$addFields: {
   "coverage" : { "paymentOption.coverage" : {$exists: true} }
}
```

... but this produces an error:

> Invalid $addFields specification: cannot use dotted field name

How would this operation need to change to produce this document?

```
{ 
    "_id" : <value>, 
    "region" : "Midwest", 
    "dob" : ISODate("1989-07-21T05:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "coverage" : {
                 "status" : "active", 
                 "coverageEnd" : ISODate("2020-07-31T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                 "coverageStart" : ISODate("2018-08-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `{
  "$addFields": {
    "coverage": "$paymentOption.coverage"
  }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "coverage": "$paymentOption.coverage"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      paymentOption: 0
    }
  }
])
```

You can see it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/shGoHDfhshk)

You ware missing the `$` operator since you are trying to access the `paymentOption` fields.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, @Akrion.